# How can I get an array of the current month's weekdays in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My best attempt is

```
Time.zone.today.all_month.select(&:on_weekday?)
```

but I just want to check if there's something more efficient yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Time.zone.today.all_month.select(&:on_weekday?)
```

Comment: To clarify, I was relying on [`Date::Calculations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html)